How to force kernel to perform data read twice from same block device?
At our embedded system we found that sometimes data read from flash receive junk, and reading again would receive right data. As part of the debug process, we like to hack the data read functions at the Linux kernel, our kernel version is 5.4.
My current target is sync_io() in dm-io.c, the plan is, after the following:
    dispatch_io(op, op_flags, num_regions, where, dp, io, 1);

    wait_for_completion_io(&sio.wait);

    if (error_bits)
        *error_bits = sio.error_bits;

I will add the following:
if (op == REQ_OP_READ) {
    dispatch_io(op, op_flags, num_regions, where, dp, io, 1);

    wait_for_completion_io(&sio.wait);
}

The idea is, as long as the operation is data read, perform another data read from the same region unconditionally. The I/O performance hit is not our concern.
Do you see problem of this plan? One thing I am not sure, after the first call of dispatch_io(), would some lower level data structures have changed their values? If so, the re-call would not re-read same region but some (subsequent?) region?

Basically your question is: "Is the dispatch_io() idempotent when the same values supplied?"

I believe it's not after browsing a while. You may condict your own research. I vote to close this as it's unknown what you have already tried and done and what is the result. (And use a bit of formating, like syntax highlighting, func() references and so on. It will help to read the question faster and easier to understand.)

Why not instead figure out why your first read is failing?  Most likely you are violating one or more timing specs.  The idea that a second read would give better results is just voodoo.
